# Filling values linear backwards with groupby

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby, interpolation

I have this df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time": [nat, '2020-04-09 06:46:00', '2020-04-09 06:46:00', '2020-04-09 06:46:00', '2020-04-09 06:46:00', '2020-04-09 06:46:00', nat, '2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515', '2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515', '2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515', '2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515'],
                  "Power": [0, 0, 0, 0, 4200, 4200, 0, 4200, 4200, 4200, 5000],
                  "Total Energy": [5200, 5200, 5200, 5200, 5500, 5600, 5600, 5600, 5600, 5900, 6100],
                  "ID": ['-', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, '-', 2, 2, 2, 2],
                  "Energy": [0, 0, 0, 0, 300, 400, 0, 0, 0, 300, 500]},
                  index=pd.date_range(start = "2020-04-09 6:45", periods = 11, freq = 'T'))
    
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'])
df['Power'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Power'], errors = 'ignore')
df['Total Energy'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Total Energy'], errors = 'coerce')
df['ID'] = pd.to_numeric(df['ID'], errors = 'coerce')
df['Energy'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Energy'], errors = 'coerce')
    
df
```

Output:

```
                                          Time  Power   Total Energy     ID Energy
2020-04-09 06:45:00                        NaT     0            5200    NaN      0
2020-04-09 06:46:00 2020-04-09 06:46:00.000000     0            5200    1.0      0
2020-04-09 06:47:00 2020-04-09 06:46:00.000000     0            5200    1.0      0
2020-04-09 06:47:00 2020-04-09 06:46:00.000000     0            5200    1.0      0
2020-04-09 06:48:00 2020-04-09 06:46:00.000000  4200            5500    1.0    300
2020-04-09 06:49:00 2020-04-09 06:46:00.000000  4200            5600    1.0    400
2020-04-09 06:50:00                        NaT     0            5600    NaN      0
2020-04-09 06:51:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515  4200            5600    2.0      0
2020-04-09 06:51:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515  4200            5600    2.0      0
2020-04-09 06:52:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515  4200            5900    2.0    300
2020-04-09 06:53:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515  5000            6100    2.0    500
```

I want to fill the column `df['Energy']` linear - groupby the column `df['Time'] (Starting with 0).

Expectet Outcome:

```
                                          Time  Power   Total Energy     ID Energy
2020-04-09 06:45:00                        NaT     0            5200    NaN      0
2020-04-09 06:46:00 2020-04-09 06:46:00.000000     0            5200    1.0      0
2020-04-09 06:47:00 2020-04-09 06:46:00.000000     0            5200    1.0    100
2020-04-09 06:47:00 2020-04-09 06:46:00.000000     0            5200    1.0    200
2020-04-09 06:48:00 2020-04-09 06:46:00.000000  4200            5500    1.0    300
2020-04-09 06:49:00 2020-04-09 06:46:00.000000  4200            5600    1.0    400
2020-04-09 06:50:00                        NaT     0            5600    NaN      0
2020-04-09 06:51:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515  4200            5600    2.0      0
2020-04-09 06:51:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515  4200            5600    2.0    150
2020-04-09 06:52:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515  4200            5900    2.0    300
2020-04-09 06:53:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515  5000            6100    2.0    500
```

I've tried this: `df['Energy'] = df.groupby('Time')['Energy'].apply(lambda x: x.interpolate())` , but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your code - it is in the data and use of interpolation.

The interpolate() function is used to fill NA values in the dataframe or series... but in your dataframe - the Energy series has '0s' which will not be applied in the interpolation.

I did a minor mod on your data to demonstrate. Note that the Energy series has changed to have np.nans in the areas that you want 'interpolated'

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Time": [nat, '2020-04-09 06:46:00', '2020-04-09 06:46:00', '2020-04-09 06:46:00', '2020-04-09 06:46:00', '2020-04-09 06:46:00', nat, '2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515', '2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515', '2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515', '2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515'],
                  "Power": [0, 0, 0, 0, 4200, 4200, 0, 4200, 4200, 4200, 5000],
                  "Total Energy": [5200, 5200, 5200, 5200, 5500, 5600, 5600, 5600, 5600, 5900, 6100],
                  "ID": ['-', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, '-', 2, 2, 2, 2],
                  "Energy": [np.nan, 0, np.nan, np.nan, 300, 400, np.nan, 0, np.nan, 300, 500]},
                  index=pd.date_range(start = "2020-04-09 6:45", periods = 11, freq = 'T'))
```

NOW when you run this...

```
df['Energy'] = df.groupby('Time')['Energy'].apply(lambda x: x.interpolate())
print(df)
```

You will get this:

```
                                      Time  Power  Total Energy   ID  Energy
2020-04-09 06:45:00                        NaT      0          5200  NaN     NaN
2020-04-09 06:46:00 2020-04-09 06:46:00.000000      0          5200  1.0     0.0
2020-04-09 06:47:00 2020-04-09 06:46:00.000000      0          5200  1.0   100.0
2020-04-09 06:48:00 2020-04-09 06:46:00.000000      0          5200  1.0   200.0
2020-04-09 06:49:00 2020-04-09 06:46:00.000000   4200          5500  1.0   300.0
2020-04-09 06:50:00 2020-04-09 06:46:00.000000   4200          5600  1.0   400.0
2020-04-09 06:51:00                        NaT      0          5600  NaN     NaN
2020-04-09 06:52:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515   4200          5600  2.0     0.0
2020-04-09 06:53:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515   4200          5600  2.0   150.0
2020-04-09 06:54:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515   4200          5900  2.0   300.0
2020-04-09 06:55:00 2020-04-09 06:50:16.268515   5000          6100  2.0   500.0
```

I do not know the source of your data or intention - so I did not make further recommendations on how to change the data structure.  There are numerous ways to do that depending on your goal.